# Chef clients are unable to connect after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: chef, couchdb

After I upgraded Ubuntu on my chef server from 10.04 to 10.10, all my knife and chef clients stopped working. I received 401: Unauthorized exceptions for every query and operation.

I tried reregistering my clients (`knife client reregister CLIENT`) which didn't work.

I tried regenerating my chef authentication data (removed `/etc/chef/validation.pem`, restarted `chef-server`, and ran `knife configure --initial` on the server with `chef-validation` as the admin user and the newly generated `/etc/chef/validation.pem` as the certificate) which enabled my to connect to chef again with my new credentials, but now my configuration data is empty! Running `knife node list` for instance returns nothing.

This indicated that the CouchDB database is empty. And indeed, there is a `/var/lib/couchdb/0.10.0/chef.couch` file of 1.1GB, and an almost empty `/var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1/chef.couch` file.

I am still figuring out how to recover my data, but has anyone have similar experience? How did you manage to migrate your chef database to the new CouchDB version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by copying the data from `/var/lib/couchdb/0.10.0/` to `/var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1/` while couch and chef were stopped. Remember to also copy the `.chef_design` folder and setting the owner to `couchdb`! Now my old clients and knife can connect without any problems.

I did have to recreate the RabbitMQ virtual host as described in http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Indexer.